# Octopus Deploy - Managing version numbers with multiple channels

Tags: release-management, devops, octopus-deploy

We have just started using Octopus Deploy.

We have 3 channels

- **Beta** (For a QA life-cycle - cannot be promoted further)
- **Stable** (Full life-cycle - can be promoted to UAT, Staging & Production)
- **Hotfix** (Life-cycle can skip any environment)

Is there a way so that each channel creates its version number differently, but uses the same seed for its numbers?

i.e.

- **Beta** increments revision + has channel name: `1.0.1-beta`, `1.0.2-beta`, `1.0.3-beta` etc
- **Stable** increments minor: `1.1.0`, `1.2.0`, `1.3.0` etc
- **Hotfix** increments revision: `1.1.1`, `1.1.2`, `1.1.3` etc

Whilst this seems desirable to me - is there an argument for not doing it this way?

Answer (score 1):

With deployment automation you want to keep as much as possible the same between deployments - Octopus helps with this.

For example, Octopus will version the process, variables, and packages for a release so that changes to these won't apply throughout the entire lifespan of the release.

So when you pop 1.1.0 of your code into Octopus, it generates Release 1.1.0 and snapshots the process and variables for that release so they are isolated from any change.

If you upload 1.1.0BETA of your code, then decide "it is a candidate for release", you'd then upload 1.1.0 and it would be different code, a different release and a different snapshot of the process and variables. You would then have to flow it through from scratch through your entire lifecycle. If you have already performed testing against 1.1.0 BETA, that wouldn't be valid for 1.1.0 - so you'd have to duplicate effort.

Doing things the "out of the box" way, you'd upload 1.1.0 and flow it through your QA environment and either block it as a bad release, or promote it as a good release - ensuring that everything is consistent and you only have to do things once.

Can you manage the labelling of "BETA", "RC", and "RTM" in another way (i.e. through variable substitution) so you could keep everything else the same?

Answer (score 0):

You should version the packages with your build server.(Like Jenkins,TFS..)  There are lots of plugins and formatting templates for versioning. Especially Octopus is a deployment tool not versioning tool.

**With Jenkins MSbuild** (Jenkins builds Octopus deploys for me)

- 2016.4.28.2-dev
- 2016.4.28.1-main
- 2016.3.25.1-hotfix

  ${BUILD_YEAR}.${BUILD_MONTH}.${BUILD_DAY}.${BUILDS_TODAY}-branchname

**With TFS Build**
Open TFS build definition Process, Open advanced  and check for "Build number format" You should use this.

$(Date:yy.MMdd.HH.mm)

Answer (score 0):

*"is there an argument for not doing it this way?"* Yes there is. You want Octopus to enforce which versions are used with which Channels. Octopus Channels are controlled using versioning rules based on a version range and SemVer tags. Two of your channels are not distinguishable in SemVer terms, so the Package version number format would need to be altered to allow the Channel version rules to work. Given that basis, achieving what you want would mean that the Release version number does not correspond to the Package version number (well, not if you derive the Release number from the package's version number, which has always seemed the sensible option to me, to avoid having to manage version numbers in two places, and also I'm assuming you agree it's sensible for Release `1.2.3` to contain Packages with the same version number). However, with a *slight* concession on the Release version number, you can get close to what you want...

Your **Beta** channel is fine, no problem: give a pre-release tag of `beta` on the version rule for that channel. But the problem is distinguishing these two:

- **Stable** increments minor: `1.1.0`, `1.2.0`, `1.3.0` etc
- **Hotfix** increments revision: `1.1.1`, `1.1.2`, `1.1.3` etc

Sadly it isn't possible to create a rule based on the entire version number (e.g. with a Regular Expression: `\.0$`). We would have liked exactly that rule for exactly the same reason as you. So unless you're willing to manually add a version rule for each possible version ending in `.0` (I'll assume not...) then we have to make a small concession to fit in with what Octopus wants.

You would need to choose one of those two channels to also have a SemVer pre-release tag, like you have for **Beta**. Let's say we add a `-hotfix` suffix to the **Hotfix** versions. Then you need to set the version rule for the Hotfix channel to have `hotfix` as the pre-release tag. And you must change the **Stable** channel to have a version rule of `^$` (meaning that there is no tag) to prevent releases from the other channels being used in this channel.

The above gives you what you want, with the slight concession that all the **Hotfix** releases have a `-hotfix` suffix. And it would be easy to get an automated build to decide to add that suffix when it creates a package if the version number isn't a beta, and doesn't end in `.0`.